# HP All-in-one inkjet printer doesn't print well

Tags: printer, inkjet-printer

I'm trying to fix a problem with an HP All-in-one inkjet printer. It might look like the ink should be replaced, but a new ink cartridge doesn't make a difference. The ink levels of the old cartridge seem OK as well. The colors work well and don't have this problem. It's black only that has a problem. I used the HP software to clean the heads, but that doesn't make a difference.

Could this be the black head having a problem? What can I do to fix this?

[image: Example of problem]

What you see is scan of a small part of a print. The blackness stays the same over horizontal lines. For most of the page, black text is pale grey.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like the head has dried out. The printer is exactly three years old and used regularly although not daily. Because replacing the head is quite expensive I've bought a new printer.

Answer (score -1):

In your printer property page, or through the HP printer icon(usually in systray), look for the clean nozzal / clean head feature. You may have to do it multiple times.

You may also consider replacing the black cartage too.

Comment: As I've mentioned in my question, I used the clean-head feature and I tried another cartridge.

Comment: I said you have to do it multiple times. That is how we fix clogged head sometimes. Depends on your luck, it may work or not work.

Comment: I tried it multiple times, but it didn't work.

Comment: As I said, this depends on luck. Sometimes 4-6 runs will improve it and you can continue trying. But usually if no improvement after 3 runs, try switch cartridge, if still no improvement, switch the printer if it is one of those home use model. They got so cheap now getting a new one (they come with small cartridges!!) is cheaper than replacing all the cartridges. The problem with small/home printer nowadays is they are so cheap that not worth the time to investigate the problem or even drive them back to the shop. It is a huge waste of material(IMHO).